# All Sql developer connections getting affected from sqlplus

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I'm new to Oracle SQL and so I'm quite troubled with this problem. I have Oracle 11g, SQL Developer, sqlplus installed in my machine. I have created the following two connections in sqldeveloper:

```
Connection Name      Username    Password
dbms                  SYSTEM     maharshi
test                  SYSTEM     maharshi
```

The connection type is basic, role is default, Hostname, port and SID are all default values. i.e. localhost, 1521, xe respectively.

Now, when we select a specific database and execute statements in it's corresponding worksheet, the effect takes place w.r.t that particular connection only. i.e. if we create a table in the sql worksheet in sqldeveloper of dbms connection, then a table is shown in the dbms connection only and not in that of test connection.

But, if I login via SQLPlus as below:

```
sqlplus SYSTEM/maharshi
```

And thereafter I execute the table creation, which connection will it affect? If I execute the statement, which connection will get affected(dbms or test)? Suppose I want to create a table in the dbms connection only via sqlplus, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly, so I apologize in advance.

It does not matter what is your Connection Name in SQL Developer. What matters is a Username. You work in the schema of a user that you are connected to. In your case both of your connections are from the user SYSTEM. So if you create a table in the dbms connection you will have access to this table from the test connection. The same goes for the sqlplus connection.

Bottom line: your table will be visible accross all your connections.

Comment: I would also guess that it merely looks like the table is only being created on one or the other, and that you just need to do a refresh in SQL Developer to see it show up on the other connection.

Comment: When I'm logging via sqlplus and creating tables, then which connection would get affected(dbms or test)?